# How to display arrays dynamically

Tags: java

public class globe

```
public static int line1[] = {1,4,7,10,13};
public static int line2[] = {1,5,7,11,13};
public static int line2[] = {1,5,7,11,13};
```

public class test

```
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{
   String temp = "line"+i;
   System.out.println(globe.temp);// how to get array hole value
}
```

How to get the array value in globe class? I need to get specific array values from for loop given line number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the current state of your code, this would require reflection. However, if you need to do such a thing, **maybe the design of the `Globe` class is not right in the first place**.

You need to express the link between your lines within the code, if you want to use them the way you shew us. What about using a 2-dimensional array?

```
public static final int[][] lines = {
    {1,4,7,10,13},
    {1,5,7,11,13},
    {1,5,7,11,13}
};
```

And then use it this way:

```
for (int[] line : Globe.lines) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(line));
}
```

> Note that the Globe class name should be capitalized, to be consistent with Java conventions.

---

For the sake of the example, here is how to do it with reflection **in the case you don't control the `Globe` class**:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    String fieldName = "line" + i;
    Field lineField = Globe.class.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
    int[] line = lineField.get(null); // null for static fields
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(line));
}
```